# Using aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp-v2 with CMake

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake, aws-iot

I'm attempting to build an application using the AWS IOT device sdk for C++.

I was able to clone, build and install the library with CMake and Visual Studio.  Now I'm trying to include the IotShadow library into my test application through CMake.

I've included the package in my CMakeLists.txt file as follows and included the path the library install through the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable.

```
find_package(IotShadow-cpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TestApp IotShadow-cpp)
```

CMake runs fine and things seem to be setup. However when I attempt to build, the IotShadow header files are not found.  I've confirmed that `IotShadow-cpp_DIR` is correct and that the header files do exist.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Has anyone successfully used the SDK on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the target for `find_package` is correct but the target for `target_link_libraries` needs to be `AWS::IotShadow-cpp`.

The following seemed to work for me:

```
find_package(IotShadow-cpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TestApp AWS::IotShadow-cpp)
```